# {subscribe / subscribe to / subscribe for}

Tags: word-meaning

> I subscribe **to** the book called *Pride and Prejudice*.
>   I subscribe **for** the book called *Pride and Prejudice*.
>   I subscribe the book called *Pride and Prejudice*.

What is the difference?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're after with this question?  What do you not understand about it?  None of the sentences really make a lot of sense without context, honestly.  (I can invent scenarios in which the first two do, but it's a stretch.)

Comment: You subscribe to a journal, magazine, newspaper, or a service, etc. so that you can receive it regularly.  To subscribe to the book  "Pride and Prejudice " doesn't make much sense. You subscribe for shares, bonds, etc., not for a book. You subscribe an amount of money, and you subscribe a document implying to sign to testify its contents. Maybe you subscribe (sign) a book to approve or testify its contents.